# How can I Build a macosx app with Release Scheme?

Tags: toolchain

I have recently installed XCode 14.3 and am now having problems Building a macos app as Release. The Build fails with the following error message:
File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_macosx.a
Building the app with Debug Scheme still works.
I have also installed Swift 5.8 Toolchain but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to resolve the problem.

- Solution 1: [Restore ARC library](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/3333#issuecomment-1500818983)

  The ARC library was removed in Xcode 14.3, but you can restore it by executing the following commands:

  ```bash
  cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/
  sudo mkdir arc
  cd arc
  sudo git clone https://github.com/kamyarelyasi/Libarclite-Files.git .
  sudo chmod +x *
  ```
- Solution 2: [Change MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET](https://github.com/chipsenkbeil/choose/issues/37#issuecomment-1504499227)

  Set `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to `10.13` or above, or directly set it as `$(RECOMMENDED_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)`.

  You can set it in the following two locations in the project, and they are equivalent:

  - TARGETS → General → Minimum Deployment: `$(RECOMMENDED_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)`
  - TARGETS → Build Settings → Deployment → macOS Deployment Target: `Recommended (macOS 10.14.6)`